# How to: Line 3D effect?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, 3d, lettering

How would one go about creating a lined 3D effect as shown in the image below?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Copy original shape
- paste behind
- move pasted shape so it is offset from original shape
- fill pasted shape with pattern
- adjust edges of pasted shape to align with original path.

[image: text]

**TIP**
You never need to create a diagonal line pattern in Illustrator. Simply create a vertical or horizontal line pattern, then apply it to a shape and use Object > Transform > Rotate. Untick the Transform Objects box (the Transform Patterns box will auto-tick) and enter the angle you want the lines. This is ***much*** easier than creating actual angled patterns. (Photoshop can't do this in case anyone is wondering).